# How to write a regex to capture letters separated by punctuation in Python 3?

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex and encountered a problem. I need to parse a list of last names and first names to use in a url and fetch an html page. In my last names or first names, if it's something like "John, Jr" then it should only return John but if it's something like "J.T.R", it should return "JTR" to make the url work. Here is the code I wrote but it doesn't capture "JTR".

```
import re
last_names_parsed=[]
for ln in last_names:
    L_name=re.match('\w+', ln)
    last_names_parsed.append(L_name[0])
```

However, this will not capture J.T.R properly. How should I modify the code to properly handle both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `\.` to the regular expression:

```
import re
final_data = [re.sub('\.', '', re.findall('(?<=^)[a-zA-Z\.]+', i)[0]) for i in last_names]
```

Regex explanation:

`(?<=^)`: positive lookbehind, ensures that the ensuring regex will only register the match if the match is found at the beginning of the string

`[a-zA-Z\.]`: matches any occurrence of alphabetical characters: [a-zA-Z], along with a period `.`

`+`: searches the previous regex (`[a-zA-Z\.]`) as long as a period or alphabetic character is found. For instance, in `"John, Jr"`, only `John` will be matched, because the comma `,` is not included in the regex expression `[a-zA-Z\.]`, thus halting the match.

Comment: This does work. Do you mind explaining your code to me as I am very new to regex.

Comment: @Josh please see my recent edit.

Comment: Now it's clear. Thanks.